# ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 2, 2) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am following a new book that I recently got but I'm getting this error and I don't know what I've done wrong

ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 2, 2) and (None, 10) are incompatible

here is the code

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

network.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', 
           loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
           metrics=['accuracy'])

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1, batch_size = 128)
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: its says the last line

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Error is likely in the way you are preprocessing the data, post the complete code if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The code you post seems fine and I just run it! It works.
I think you're having problems importing the dataset the right way.
I used the MNIST dataset to test your code and I put a comment in front of the import lines.
Try to replicate it and tell me if the problem persists.

```py
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = mnist.load_data() # Load mnist
# I wrote train_X... but changed it later 

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

network.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', 
           loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
           metrics=['accuracy'])

train_images = train_X.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_X.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

train_labels = to_categorical(train_y)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_y)

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1, batch_size = 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

- I have run the code using mnist and, I think the problem is with the way you are preprocessing the `train_labels`. You are probably applying the function `to_categorical()` to already categorical data leading to dimensionality error.
- Print the dimensions of `train_labels` and make sure it has dimension similar to `(60000, 10)`. 60000 may vary but the second value in the tuple should be 10.